# Problems with Dependencies after switching to TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have just switched one of my React Projects over to TypeScript, which is actually my first time using it. So I renamed my App.jsx file to App.tsx and got some errors with my dependencies. Most of them I could fix by using `npm i @types/{package}`. There are three errors left though:

1) For two of my packages, there is no @types package, as they aren't that popular. It says *"Could not find a declaration file for module [...] [...]/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. [...]"* In the rest of the error it says that I should try to install the @types package if it exists, which doesn't. If it doesn't exist, it says something about some declaration file, but I wasn't able to find any information about that online.

2) It almost says the exact same thing for the 'react' package, even though I installed the @types package of it. Instead of telling me to install the package it says: *"If the 'react' package actually exposes this module, consider sending a pull request to amend 'https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react'"* which I don't understand what it is supossed to mean.

Also, I copied the tsconfig.json from the create-react-app typescript template (`create-react-app {name} --typescript`

Answer (score 1):

1) You can make a `types` folder where you will keep all the declarations that you can't find under @types. Basically you make a `some-react-component.d.ts` file where you declare:

```
declare module "some-react-component";
```

2) You can try to import react this way: `import * as React from "react";` and see if that's fixing it.

Comment: I fixed the react import now. Thanks. But where do I have to put the types folder? In the root directory of the project or in the src directory?

Comment: I put mine in the root directory

Comment: So I have tried putting the file in there, but a) it gives me an error when I only do "declare" (can not find name "declare") and when I use "declare module" there is no error within the file, but in my App.tsx it still tells me the exact same error.

Comment: Yes, it was actually declare module. I edited my response. Try to open and close the editor. I had some issues with vscode not detecting the declaration but after I restarted the editor, it worked.